# SQL Server filter content Chinese vs English

Tags: sql-server

May I know is there any SQL Script to fulfill my below scenario?

If `column1` contain Chinese character, update value `column2` to 'Chinese'
If `column1` contain English character, update value `column2` to 'English'.

Comment: you can select it without writing N and compare it with '?' (SELECT '朱亚丽' = ???), if it is not english and your server's default language is english, it will tell you. (from the top of my head, worth a try!)

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: How many characters can Column1 contain?  Can you provide some sample records?

Comment: the column1 i refer to is about address of some client, column2 is the language of statement the system generate, 'big5' vs 'eng'

Comment: Hi @DarwinChan, please show us your steps ...

Answer (score 3):

You can check column values for english using like operator.

```
UPDATE table1
SET col2= CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]' THEN'English'
          ELSE 'chinese' END
```

Comment: dear thanks for your help, however i found the col2 will change to 'Chinese' when col1 starts with digits.

Comment: your col1 contains alphabets and number.?

Comment: @sahi, i check even the col1 contains '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'  will still update, how about if the col1 start with '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%' , then change col2 value?

Comment: didn't get you point..?  change LIKE part to LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT(varchar(max), column1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` to compare with original column to check if it contains any Unicode characters

[Sample](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422531)

```
UPDATE table
SET column2 = 
   CASE 
       WHEN column1 = CONVERT(varchar(max), column1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN THEN 'English' 
       ELSE 'Chinese' -- Although the test is for Unicode, not only Chinese
   END
```